# Include name in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I set up devise and it works well. I however would also like to add the name element to the user.

So therefore I added this in my rake db:migrate file:

```
  create_table(:users) do |t|
    t.string :name #added
    ...
```

And added this in my application_helper

```
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

 def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :name
 end
```

And added this in my view (register/new)

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter name" %>
  </div>
```

And run rake db:migrate

But now when I try to run register I get
     undefined method `name' for #

any thoughts what goes wrong here?

Comment: You are changed already applied migration. Drop db, create db and apply migrations again.

Comment: Did you try restarting the app? Sometimes it's necesary for it to pick up changes.

Answer (score 1):

As maxd mentioned in his comment, you have already run the migration, so it will not be run again.

You have two options.

1. drop your database and recreate it.
2. Create a separate migration to add the `name` field you are looking for.

Personally, I would go with the second. If anyone else has already run that migration, they would need to drop their databases. If you were to take this approach and already had production data, it should be considered unacceptable to lose this data.

Generally speaking, if you have already run a migration successfully, you should avoid editing it.

Answer (score 1):

Like everyone said, you should probably do a second migration and add a column to your :users table.

Documentation Link:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_column